# is this memory leak on iOS / Android

Tags: react-native, memory, expo, tensorflow.js

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBPG7.png

so everytime i trained a model, numTensors is increasing, im just wondering if this is bad or not ?
and when i close the apps, and start load the model and trained new model, it keeps increasing
is it bad when i got so many model ? and how to fix this ?

I am using knn-classifier to addExample

```
      const collectData = async (className) => {
    console.log(`[+] Class ${className} selected`)
    setStatus(statusList[1])
    setIsLoading(true)
    try {
      if (this.camera) {
        let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({
          skipProcessing: true,
        });
        //2. resize images into width:224 height:224
        image = await resizeImage(photo.uri, 224, 224);
        let imageTensor = base64ImageToTensor(image.base64);
        console.log(imageTensor + " imagTensor")
        //3. get embeddings from mobilenet
        let embeddings = await mobilenetModel.infer(imageTensor, true);
        console.log(embeddings + " embeddings")
        //4. train knn classifier
        knnClassifierModel.addExample(embeddings, className)
        let tempCountExamples = countExamples + 1
        let tempCountClassExamples = countClassExamples
        tempCountClassExamples[`${className}`] = tempCountClassExamples[`${className}`] + 1
        setCountExamples(tempCountExamples)
        setCountClassExamples(tempCountClassExamples)
        console.log("[+] Class Added")
      }
    } catch {
      console.log("[-] No Camera")
    }
    setIsLoading(false)
  }
```

so i updated the code with tf.tidy and tf.engine
collectdata func

```
    collectData = async () => {
    if (this.camera && this.state.label != "" && this.state.label!= null) {
        try {
            tf.engine().startScope()
            let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({
                skipProcessing: true,
            });
            //2. resize images into width:224 height:224
            const image = await this.resizeImage(photo.uri, 224, 224);
            let imageTensor = this.base64ImageToTensor(image.base64);
            //3. get embeddings from mobilenet
            console.log("=========== before dispose ===========\n " + JSON.stringify(tf.memory()) + "=================================")
            // do your thing
            let embeddings = await this.model.infer(imageTensor, true);
            tf.dispose(imageTensor);
            //4. train knn classifier
            this.knnClass.addExample(embeddings, this.state.label)
            let dataset = this.knnClass.getClassifierDataset()
            let stringDataset = JSON.stringify(Object.entries(dataset).map(([label, data]) => [label, Array.from(data.dataSync()), data.shape]))
            tf.engine().endScope()
            console.log("=========== after dispose ===========\n " + JSON.stringify(tf.memory()) + "=================================")
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error ' + err)
        }
    } else {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
    }
}
```

and the function called when snap / train the model

```
takePicture = async function () {
    console.log('snap hit!')
    await tf.tidy(() => { this.collectData(); return undefined; })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you would have to dispose of the tensors after making predictions on them otherwise the tensors will build up and cause a memory leak. You can use `tf.tidy()` for this.

The tensor is getting disposed but the value disposed by `collectData()` is returned instead. You can make the function passed as argument to `tf.tidy()` not return any Tensor:

```
tf.tidy(() => { collectData(); return undefined; })
```

You could also use this to clean any unused tensors in async code :

```
tf.engine().startScope()
// do your thing
tf.engine().endScope()
```

Comment: after that dispose, im using predict from knnclassifier, do i need to dispose of it too or not ?

`let prediction = await this.knnClass.predictClass(embeddings);`

Comment: No I do not think that you have to dispose of the embeddings, just the tensors.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UWTBpg8.png

just to make sure, im trying to add 3 example train model, but still increasing, is this how is it supposed to be ?

Comment: Try ```console.table(tf.memory());``` before and after disposing the tensor.

Comment: thank you @yudhiesh 

anyway, in this pic, im giving you before, after train model, it seems fine, but when i re-open my page, it start loading up the model and the tensor increasing again, is it normal or not ?

https://i.imgur.com/W5KZWlQ.png

Comment: Even with the code I updated the answer with? Are you printing the tensors before this function is called and after?

Comment: i updated the code with your suggestion,

and the result with before, after, and first load https://i.imgur.com/W5KZWlQ.png

Comment: `tf.tidy()` is not an asynchronous function so try removing that. If it does not work try the second answer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PArCMbw

the tensor everytime i train new model is not increasing, and its good i think,
the problem now is everytime i close the page and re-open the page, tensor start increasing even im not train any model, is it normal ?

Comment: Yes that is the expected behavior, for the latter issue you should only start processing the tensors once the model is loaded to prevent that from happening. Example `modelLoaded && takePicture()` or you could attach a boolean which changes according to if the model is loaded or not.